# How to change ip address to domain name in ionic application

Tags: docker, ionic-framework, dns, hybrid-mobile-app

I ported webogram to ionic, after doing so I uploaded it inside a docker container on a server. When I visit the page using the domain name it loads the page but in the url bar is shows the registered ip address the domain is tied to instead of the domain name I'd like to see (like www.mywebsite.com). I already checked namecheap and the ip is indeed being masked so my question is this: Where do you think the problem is? the docker container that needs to be started with some specific parameters or ionic application might have some variable that needs to be set. I've tried looking for an answer but I didn't see anyone that had a similar situation to mine.

Comment: I'd also like to add the github to the webogram project is here https://github.com/zhukov/webogram

Comment: I get a problem similar to this https://wordpress.org/support/topic/browser-displaying-ip-instead-of-domain-name